# Scan Values in a Range and Highlight If There is a Match

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column with transaction values. I want to create a FOR loop which will find the opposite number of a value (like finding -10 for 10) and highlight both the cells.

I have written a double FOR loop which takes a lot of time because there are more 2000 lines in the database.

Is there a faster way to do it?

TL;DR I want to find two equal and opposite values in a given range and highlight both of them.

Comment: In my opinion, a good case for Dictionary

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far

Comment: Did not know that Dictionaries were in VBA as well. I tried writing a code with dictionaries as well. But like Python, I am not sure how add a list to a dictionary value.

So far I have written this:

Dim dict As Object
Dim cl As Range, rng As Range
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Set rng = Range("AH" & AbsStart & ":AH" & AHEnd)

For Each cl In rng.Cells
    dict(cl.Row) = dict(cl.Row) + 1
Next

Dim VarKey As Variant

For Each VarKey In dict.Keys()
    If dict(VarKey) = 2 Then
        
    
Next

I want to retain those row numbers to highlight them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
Sub HL_Opposite()
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    t = Timer
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ActiveSheet
        Set Rng = Intersect(.Columns("A"), .UsedRange)
        Rng.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
        
        a = Rng ' get all the values from range to array (to speed up)
        
        For Each v In a
            If Not dict.Exists(v) Then dict.Add v, False
            If dict.Exists(-v) Then
                dict(v) = True ' mark the opposit entries as True
                dict(-v) = True ' mark the opposit entries as True
            End If
        Next
        
        For r = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
            If dict(a(r, 1)) Or dict(-a(r, 1)) Then ' check if tha value marked as opposite
                Rng(1).Offset(r - 1).Interior.Color = vbRed
            End If
        Next
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Debug.Print "Done in " & Timer - t & " sec."
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Woah! Thanks a lot for taking the time out. I am a newbie when it comes to VBA. Getting Type Mismatch error. What do I declare 'a' as?

Comment: `Dim a as Variant` or `Dim a`

Comment: This works well but there is one more problem. If I have (10,10 and -10) in the range, it's highlighting all 3 of them. I only want to highlight entries which have a pair only (like 32 and -32).

Comment: and if the situation is (10,10,10,10 and -10,-10) - which "10" and "-10" should be tinted? first, last, middle or what? I think it needs to be clear logic first.

Comment: None of them. A human will check on those lines then. Currently we are checking a huge number of lines. I just want to reduce that count by removing these obvious pairs. Rest of them, we can continue to check manually.